# Get counts of rows by value in single query

Tags: mysql, join

What I mean:

Imagine these tables:

```
Table article_status:             Table users:

userid  | article | status        id | name
--------+---------+-------        ---+------
 1      | 1       | 1              1 | Peter
 1      | 2       | 2              2 | Bob
 2      | 3       | 1
 2      | 4       | 1
 2      | 5       | 2
 2      | 6       | 2
 2      | 7       | 3
```

What I want to get is the count of all items grouped by status number for a user.
The number of possible status values is known (4).

Example result for `users.id = 2`:

```
userid | name | s1_count | s2_count | s3_count | s4_count |
-------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 2     | Bob  | 2        | 2        | 1        | 0        |
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS userid
, u.name
, COUNT(s1.status) AS s1_count
, COUNT(s2.status) AS s2_count
, COUNT(s3.status) AS s3_count
, COUNT(s4.status) AS s4_count
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN article_status AS s1 ON s1.userid = u.id AND s1.status = 1 
INNER JOIN article_status AS s2 ON s2.userid = u.id AND s2.status = 2 
INNER JOIN article_status AS s3 ON s3.userid = u.id AND s3.status = 3 
INNER JOIN article_status AS s4 ON s4.userid = u.id AND s4.status = 4 
WHERE u.id = :uid
LIMIT 1
```

But this doesn't works (why?) and it looks very suboptimal.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a known quantity of status values? Or will the number of statuses be unknown?

Comment: "The number of possible status values is known (4)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` to get the result:

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  u.name,
  sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END) s1_count,
  sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 2 THEN 1 else 0 END) s2_count,
  sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 3 THEN 1 else 0 END) s3_count,
  sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 4 THEN 1 else 0 END) s4_count
FROM users u
INNER JOIN article_status a 
  ON u.id = a.userid
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ece92/11)

Or you can use a lot of subqueries to return the data:

```
select u.id,
  u.name,
  coalesce(s1_count, 0) s1_count,
  coalesce(s2_count, 0) s2_count,
  coalesce(s3_count, 0) s3_count,
  coalesce(s4_count, 0) s4_count
from users u
left join
(
  select count(*) s1_count, userid
  from article_status
  where status = 1
  group by userid
) s1
  on u.id = s1.userid
left join
(
  select count(*) s2_count, userid
  from article_status
  where status = 2
  group by userid
) s2
  on u.id = s2.userid
left join
(
  select count(*) s3_count, userid
  from article_status
  where status = 3
  group by userid
) s3
  on u.id = s3.userid
left join
(
  select count(*) s4_count, userid
  from article_status
  where status = 4
  group by userid
) s4
  on u.id = s4.userid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ece92/8)

Answer (score 2):

This is known as *pivoting* your data... one way to do this is by using `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT 
  u.id
, u.name
, COUNT(CASE WHEN a_s.status = 1 THEN 1 END) AS s1_count
, COUNT(CASE WHEN a_s.status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS s2_count
, COUNT(CASE WHEN a_s.status = 3 THEN 1 END) AS s3_count
, COUNT(CASE WHEN a_s.status = 4 THEN 1 END) AS s4_count
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN article_status AS a_s ON a_s.userid = u.id 
WHERE u.id = :uid
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm going to use your solution but I've accepted bluefeet's one because it's more complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing something like COUNT(s1.status), try the following

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(s1.article, '-', s1.status)))
```

That's just a theory of mine, as it will count distinctly on the status and article. Tell me if it works!

Comment: I feel unconfortable using CONCATs here